# CompletableFuture get result without blocking

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

```
private static boolean validateSMTP(final ArrayList mxList, String address) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
  ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(mxList.size());
  List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> allVerifiers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int mx = 0; mx < mxList.size(); mx++) {
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> verifier = createAsyncVerifier((String) mxList.get(mx), address, pool);
        verifier.thenApply(isvalid -> isvalid);
        verifier.get();
    }
  return false;
}
```

In the above code I want to create `mxList.size()` `CompletableFuture`, execute each. If the result of any of them is `true` I want to break the loop, when I used the `get()` method it blocks and I waste the benefit of concurrency, any idea about how to do that?

Comment: Use a [`CompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html). Make the tasks interruptible (otherwise you gain very little) -  when you recieve an invalid result then cancel all the remaining tasks. There's a good example in the documentation for [`ExecutorCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider , but do you have an idea about how to do that using CompletableFuture ?

Comment: Given that you have a tool specifically designed for the job, why? You can do it trivially by using `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` to dump the results into a `BlockingQueue` and having your main thread `take()` and process the results as they become available - hey, this is exactly what `CompletionService` does.

Comment: Incidentally - what is the purpose of `verifier.thenApply(isvalid -> isvalid)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation that submits all tasks and then gets results, returning on the first `true` result:

```
private static boolean validateSMTP(final ArrayList<String> mxList, String address)
        throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(mxList.size());

    return mxList.stream()
            .map(mx -> createAsyncVerifier(mx, address, pool))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture<Boolean>::join)
            .filter(b -> b)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

The `.collect(Collectors.toList())` ensures that **all** tasks are submitted. In the second stream, `join` is called, but this doesn't cause unnecessary waits as all tasks are already submitted.

`findFirst` will return as soon as the first element passes the filter.

Comment: This waits for all items to complete, which is fine. It would be better to failfast I imagine - but this is perfectly acceptable as a first cut.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It won't wait for all tasks to complete. `.map(CompletableFuture<Boolean>::join)` will wait for completion one element at a time, but that will be after all tasks have been submitted to the executor service (and can be expected to run concurrently up to the capacity of the pool).

Comment: `.map(CompletableFuture<Boolean>::join)` will wait for tasks to complete - of course they run in parallel, which is why you have my vote. My point is that using a `CompletionService` or similar allows you to cancel the rest of things in flight/queued as soon as the first thing fails/succeeds or whatever.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I hear that, thanks for clarifying. `Stream.findFirst()` is a short-circuiting stream operation, meaning it will stop the stream as soon as the first `true` value is encountered, without waiting for all remaining `.map(CompletableFuture<Boolean>::join)

Comment: The other issue is obviously that the first `CompletableFuture` in the `List` might be the longest running; it's rather unlikely it will be the shortest running...

Comment: @BoristheSpider 100%. In addition to that, the size of the pool also matters (I assumed it's configured accordingly)

Comment: thanks a lot @ernest_k, but do you have an idea on how to optimize it much more as it takes about 11.446 second to complete? createAsyncVerifier is doing some dns lookup behind

Comment: @BersiusAjax I believe this code will use the maximum parallelism afforded by the pool. So the first thing to configure correctly is the capacity of your thread pool. If you have many tasks, you might also benefit from making the second stream parallel (`.collect(Collectors.toList()).parallelStream()...`), but this will be negligible unless some tasks run abnormally longer than others, as mentioned by BoristheSpider, but it might improve it.